# In windows phone 7 is it possible to put a gradient colour inside a textblock?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, textblock

In windows phone 7 is it possible to put a gradient colour inside a textblock?

For example in the XAML part is there a way to indicate style and apply a linear gradient?

Also if so can the gradient be applied dynamically

Comment: See Ku6oprs answere. In addition you can define in your source file a new LinearGradientBrush with multiple GradientStops. If this is done, you are be able to assign this LinearGradientBrush to TextBlock.Foreground . This means you can modify your gradients dynamical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for foreground

```
<TextBlock.Foreground>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF6565" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</TextBlock.Foreground>
```

If you need fill background - put textblock inside container